# chrome not showing 200 status on apollo requests

Tags: google-chrome, graphql, apollo

I am using apollo client to query the server, and I can see the request is being sent and it is successful as I can render the returned data.

But chrome only shows the `204` status code, whereas Firefox shows both `200` and `204`.

Here is the picture from Firebox

[image]

This is one from chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dumb question, but in case other making the same mistake. In network tab, make sure to select `all` instead of `xhr`.